# Dango Filter - Filter DateTime Value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

i have ***json datetime*** like this

```
{
    "datetime": "2020-09-11 11:09:52",
}
```

I tried to ***filter*** it something like this

***localhost:8000/api/v1/history?datetime=2020-09-11%2011:09:52.***

**`Here what i tried`**

```
class AuditlogFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    datetime = filters.DateTimeFilter(method="datetime_filter")

    class Meta:
        model = CRUDEvent
        fields = ['datetime']

    def datetime_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(datetime__icontains=value))
```

However i got ***empty value***. Is there a way  i can **archieve** it???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: could you also add views.py where you use this filter class, and don't now why are you trying to filter by this case `Q(datetime__icontains=value`? you want to get CRUDEvent which created in exactly datetime? I suggest you to do filter in range of time like start_datetime and end datetime

Comment: yeah, thats it. @BakhtiyarBekbergen

Comment: you want to get only one item or list of item? I guess if there are several objects for example, it will be get good to get result list of objects, and it will be good to filter by range

Comment: can u provide me any approch??

Comment: `start_datetime = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='datetime',
                                                   lookup_expr='gte')
    end_datetime = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='datetime',
                                                 lookup_expr='lte')` then add these fields in fields list inside metaclass

Answer (score 0):

filters.py

```py
class AuditlogFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_datetime = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='datetime',
                                            lookup_expr='gte')
    end_datetime = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='datetime',
                                          lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = CRUDEvent
        fields = ('start_datetime', 'end_datetime')
```

views.py

```py
class CRUDEventView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.CRUDEventSerializer
    queryset = CRUDEvent.objects.all()
    filterset_class = AuditlogFilter
```

Don't know why your filter class different from model class